# Change App Name on Google Sign In Prompt Web

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform

[image: change app name]

Even though I choose "Edit App" on the Google Cloud oauth consent screen, the name of my newly changed app is not appearing.

Answer (score 3):

If you change any of the details that appear on your OAuth consent screen, such as the app's logo, name, home page, privacy policy URI, or authorized domains, **you need to resubmit the new branding configuration for verification, and receive approval, before the updates take effect on your OAuth consent screen**. Go through this to know more about [how to verify the app](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/brand-verification).

Hope you are following below steps in changing the app name :
Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/apis/credentials/consent

Select your project >> click on OAuth Consent Screen on the left nav >> then click EDIT APP >> On the next screen you can change your app name:

[image: OAuth Consent screen]

[image: Editing App name]